# Parallel Payments using PayPal Pro

Tags: paypal

I am trying to find any document ion on this topic but could not get any help. I have already implement Direct CC payments using PayPal Pro NVP API and its working fine, but now i want to integrate Parallel payment in same way, so whenever buyer pays by credit card, payment can go to 3 different receivers, please suggest if its possible and any document ion help would be appreciated.

I have got following...

```
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/WPParallelPaymens/
```

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parallel payments are not available with Payments Pro (DoDirectPayment).  You would have to use [Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECParallelPaymens/) or the [Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/) API in order to do split payments of any kind.

With DDP your only option is receive the money  into your own account and then you could push funds to secondary accounts via the [Pay API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/).  This could be automated within an [IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/gs_IPN/) script.

Comment: Thanks for great help, that is why i could not find anything similar. Can i accept direct credit card payment using `express checkout` or `Adaptive Payments`, if yes please give some references. thanks again

Comment: Yes, but it works through "guest checkout" so people would still be redirected through PayPal's pages as opposed to filling out a form directly on your site.

Comment: you helped a lot, one more question.. is there any way to save paypal fees if i make something like parallel payment using PayAPI as you know same payment would be distributed between 3 users. Please suggest, thanks

Comment: You could play with setting the PaymentType parameter in the request to PERSONAL.  There is no fee for personal payments as long as cash funds of some sort are used (ie. PayPal or bank funds).  Senders cannot dispute these types of payments, though, so it may deter your buyers.  Keep in mind, too, that you're not getting double/triple dipped on fees.  The fee gets split between the users (or passed to a single user based on your request).